Cloud synchronisation problems from QField
I am using QField (3.2.2) and have problems synchronising my data from the mobile device to the cloud.
The error message is: "Ein Netzwerk-Fehler ist aufgetreten, bitte nochmal versuchen" (A network error occured, please try again).
I deactivated my anti-virus software (Bitdefender) and tried via WLAN and via the mobile data functions. Nothing helped.
I also looked in Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\imported projects. Unfortunately, the folder is empty.
What else can I do?
